# Why is sendmail not relaying some email to Exchange?

Tags: centos, sendmail

On my network I have an Internet facing CentOS 6.5 server running sendmail.  It receives email from my Sonicwall router running the full gambit of gateway spam and IPS services.

It then relays messages behind our NAT into Exchange 2010.  I've recently rebuilt the Sendmail server to tighten it up (Full DVD installs are never good in production) and I'm having some issues getting e-mail from a fewe senders.

When I send test email from gmail.com, outlook.com or yahoo.com to my work email, the email has no problems arriving in my Inbox.  We have a customer though whose mail seems to go to `/dev/null`.  Below is the kind of mail "storm" I'll get from that domain in `/var/log/maillog`

```
Dec 17 06:23:34 stc-mailrelay sendmail[5658]: sBHCNWnw005658: from=<JMingari@klhindustries.com>, size=0, class=0, nrcpts=3, proto=ESMTP, daemon=MTA, relay=stc-exchange [10.0.1.5]
Dec 17 06:29:36 stc-mailrelay sendmail[5703]: sBHCTWbM005703: from=<JMingari@klhindustries.com>, size=0, class=0, nrcpts=2, proto=ESMTP, daemon=MTA, relay=stc-exchange [10.0.1.5]
Dec 17 07:36:52 stc-mailrelay sendmail[5938]: sBHDao0H005938: from=<JMingari@klhindustries.com>, size=0, class=0, nrcpts=1, proto=ESMTP, daemon=MTA, relay=stc-exchange [10.0.1.5]
Dec 17 07:38:10 stc-mailrelay sendmail[5946]: sBHDc8Cu005946: from=<JMingari@klhindustries.com>, size=0, class=0, nrcpts=1, proto=ESMTP, daemon=MTA, relay=stc-exchange [10.0.1.5]
Dec 17 07:39:29 stc-mailrelay sendmail[5953]: sBHDdDRQ005953: from=<JMingari@klhindustries.com>, size=0, class=0, nrcpts=2, proto=ESMTP, daemon=MTA, relay=stc-exchange [10.0.1.5]
```

This only appears to be occurring with this one company, but I can't be sure.  When I grep maillog for a message ID (i.e. sBHDdDRQ005953 above) I usually see two entries one with a `from=<email@domain.com>` and a second with `to=<someguy@domain2.com>`.

But these email from klhindustries.com only seem to have the FROM line.  On top of that  their server appears to be trying to send the email more then once in a short period.

The email is never relayed to Exchange (I've checked tracking logs in Exchange) so it has no knowledge.  None of my other servers (i.e. my Sonicwall) are complaining nor is anyone here getting any NDRs.  Only one of the senders at the company in question has received a Delayed Delivery NDR.

The other senders have seen nothing.  I'm assuming they'll probably get Delayed Delivery eventually.  I've checked mxtoolbox.com and it says my Sendmail server is behaving correctly but for one warning, a missing SPF record.  It also shows green lights across the board for blacklist servers.  I am at a loss and confidence in e-mail around here has dropped considerably.  Does anyone have any ideas?

edit:  I have also tried sending a test email from the email address at klhindustries.com above on Wormly.com.  Those tests come through no problem.

Comment: Why don't you just have the Sonicwall send directly to Exchange?

Comment: Could you post ALL log entries related to queueid sBHCNWnw005658?

Comment: joeqwerty:  I know I'm probably creating more work for myself, but I don't trust port 25, or any ports for that matter open to the Internet from anything Microsoft.  

Andzej:  When I grep the Queue ID in maillog I only find the one entry.